# List of SharePoint CU user-centered Testcases

Tags: cumulative-update, testing

Does anybody have a list of testcases to use for CUs testing? I'm searching for testcases for common user actions like

- Document Upload
- Document Download
- Follow functions
- List Attachement
- Newsfeed
- Fill in and edit Metadata

Comment: I think you just answered your own question..

Comment: @user19952 - it's true, partly! OP is short of an existing list which pretty much covers all "common user actions".